# Cannot access another page when running webpack dev-server

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, webpack-dev-server

This is my `index.html` page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Amplify Auth Flow</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <ul class="nav justify-content-end bg-light">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a id="nav-logout" class="nav-link" href="/helloworld.html">Hello</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Main Content -->
    <section id="landing-page">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center min-vh-100">
            <div class="align-self-center">
                <h1>My Landing Page</h1>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </section>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="main.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is `package.json` file

```
{
    "name": "amplify-js-app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Amplify JavaScript Example",
    "dependencies": {
      "aws-amplify": "latest"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "copy-webpack-plugin": "^6.1.0",
      "webpack": "^4.46.0",
      "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
      "webpack-dev-server": "^4.4.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
      "start": "webpack && webpack-dev-server --mode development",
      "build": "webpack"
    }
  }
```

This is `webpack.config.js` file

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { 
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    client: {
      overlay: true,
      
    },
    hot: true,
    watchFiles: ['src/*', 'index.html']
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: ['index.html']
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ]
};
```

I use `npm start` to start webpack server. Then I go to `http://localhost:8080/` to access my index.html page. When I try to access the `hello` link from my `index.html` page to get to `helloworld.html` page, I get `Cannot GET /helloworld.html` and the network is 404.

But when I use vscode extension Open with Live Server. It works just fine. What I am thinking is the webpack server cannot find `helloworld.html` file even though it is in the same directory.

**Note**: dist folder was created after running command `npm start`.

File structure:

```
amplify-js-app (dir)
|__index.html
|__helloworld.html
|__package.json
|__package-lock.json
|__webpack.config.js
|
|dist (dir)
   |__index.html
   |__main.bundle.js
```

Comment: Which operation system you are use? Windows, mac, ...?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what happened, it could not find the file because it was all the files it needs inside dist directory. But in the `webpack.config.js`, I only tell it to include `'index.html'`. To fix it, change to `'*.html'` then it will include all HTML page into dist directory.

```
plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: ['*.html']
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ]
```